# Extracting a common code fragment in Java

Tags: java, oop, refactoring

I am quite new to Java and I am making a string parsing calculator. I have a piece of code which has some almost identical fragments which I would like being extracted into some method or so, but I could not come up with an idea how to do it.

Here is a piece of code:

```
case '+':
    current_priority = 1;
    if (last_priority < current_priority) {
        i++;
        first_operand = new Add(first_operand, parse(expression, current_priority));
    } else {
        i--;
        return first_operand;
    }
    break;
case '*':
    current_priority = 2;
    if (last_priority < current_priority) {
        i++;
        first_operand = new Multiply(first_operand, parse(expression, current_priority));
    } else {
        i--;
        return first_operand;
    }
    break;
case '/':
    current_priority = 2;
    if (last_priority < current_priority) {
        i++;
        first_operand = new Divide(first_operand, parse(expression, current_priority));
    } else {
        i--;
        return first_operand;
    }
    break;
```

I would like to get a method or something which would copy the behavior of the following fragment:

```
current_priority = x;
if (last_priority < current_priority) {
    i++;
    first_operand = new Something(first_operand, parse(expression, current_priority));
} else {
    i--;
    return first_operand;
}
```

The problem is that as far as I'm concerned I can't declare non-initialized objects in Java and for my program it's important not to run the constructor of Something (Add/Multiply/Divide) before making sure it's really needed, so passing an object to this method is not a way, I have to somehow create an object inside this method, but this seems to lead to making two switches with identical cases and I would like more elegant solution if possible. I also don't know how to reproduce the return/assignment behavior depending of a condition inside a method. I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What object do you want to create inside your method? What is your method, what should it take in as parameters, and what should it return?

Comment: I am sorry if I am missing something from your question, I just didn't quite got it

Comment: @Victor2748 by saying method I mean the extracted fragment, desired behavior of which is described in the second piece of code. My question is exactly about what and how it should be. It does not really have to be a method, I just don't know how to call it properly.

Comment: Could you post where first_operand is declared? You appear to be passing the value info the Add/Subtract, etc. constructor which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @RobertMoskal first_operand is variable where I put current operation each time. For example, when parsing "1+2+3", firstly `first_operand = 1`, then `first_operand = Add(1, parse())`, then `first_operand = Add(Add(1, 2), parse)`, then `first_operand = Add(Add(1, 2), 3)`

Answer (score 1):

A Use a `Factory`

```
current_priority = x;
if (last_priority < current_priority) {
  i++;
  first_operand = myOperationFactory.createOperand(operation, first_operand, parse(expression, current_priority));
} else {
  i--;
  return first_operand;
}

public class OperationFactory {
  public Operand createOperand(char operation, Operand firstOperand, Operand secondOperand) {
    switch (operation) {
    case '+': return new Add(firstOperand, secondOperand);
    case ...
}
```

B (advanced) use enum and reflection.

```
public enum Operations {
  ADD('+', Add.class),
  MULTIPLY('*', Multiply.class)
  ...;

  private char symbol;
  private Constructor<? extends Operation> constructor;

  public Operations(char symbol, Class<? extends Operation> clazz) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
    this.constructor= clazz.getConstructor(Operand.class, Operand.class);
  }

  public Operation create(Operand operan1, Operand operand2) {
    return constructor.newInstance(operand1, operand2);
  }

  public char getSymbol() {
    return this.symbol;
  }

  public static Operations getFromSymbol(char symbol) {
    for (Operations op : Operations.values()) {
      if (op.getSymbol() == symbol) {
        return op;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and

```
current_priority = x;
if (last_priority < current_priority) {
  i++;
  Operations operation = Operations.fromSymbol(opSymbol);
  first_operand = operation.create(first_operand, parse(expression, current_priority));
   ....
```

Comment: To be completely pedantic, there should be TWO enums (or an enum and a map). It is not good that my enum is tied to the operation representation (`+` being addition, for example), so a map where you get `Operations.ADD` from `+` would be better.

Comment: The problem is that x (or current_priority) also depends on operation symbol, and as I understood your code requires it to be set before knowing what the symbol is